# Subspace of a metric space that is closed and bounded but not compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to find a example of subspace of a metric space that is closed and bounded but not compact.

MY ATTEMPT:

Consider the set $X = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ in the discrete topology.

$\color{red}{Question 1:}$ How to make $X$ a discrete metric space?

Ans: If I endow $X$ with the discrete metric, does it becomes a discrete metric space?

$\color{red}{Question 2:}$ I want to prove $X$ (as discrete metric space) is closed, bounded but not compact.

Ans: We will choose $r>1$, then take the open ball $B_d (x, r)$ for $x \in X$, this proves $X$ is bounded.

Also, $X$ is closed because $X^c$ is union of basic open sets.

Now we will prove $X$ is not compact. Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an open cover consisting  singletons in the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$. Let $\{\frac{1}{n_k} \mid k = 1, 2, \cdots,m\} $ be a finite subcover of $X$. Choose $N = \text{max}\ \{n_1, \cdots, n_m\}$, then $\frac{1}{N+1}$ is not in  the finite subcover. Therefore, $X$ is not compact.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Can I build a discrete metric space from the discrete topological space?

Comment: Your $X$ is a closed and bounded subset of itself under its usual topology as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}$ too. In general, if you take any compact subspace of a metric space and remove a non-isolated point then the resulting space (under the subspace topology) is a closed, bounded subset of itself that is not compact.

Comment: The metric that is usually used for a discrete topological space, is defined to have $d(x, y) = 1$ unless $x = y$ and to have $d(x, x) = 0$. But as per my previous comment, you don't have to resort to the discrete metric to get an example.

Comment: trivial example: $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded when endowed with the discrete metric. the open cover $\mathcal{C}=\{\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}([0,1]):x\in[0,1]\}$ admits no finite sub-cover, since any finite subset of $\mathcal{C}$ only covers finitely many points in $[0,1]$ when there are infinitely many points in $[0,1]$. alternatively, $[0,1]$ with the discrete metric is complete, but not totally bounded, so it cannot be compact, since metric spaces are compact iff they are complete and totally bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give any set $X$ the discrete metric and the resulting topological space is the discrete one, so e.g. take $(\Bbb R,d)$ with $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$. Then any infinite subset $A$ is closed (all subsets are closed in the discrete topology, as all subsets are open) and bounded (under $d$ all non-empty subsets have diameter $1$) but not compact, as each $\{a\}$ is open (being $B_d(a,1)$) and so the singletons form an open cover for any subspace from which we cannot omit one (or we wouldn't have a cover anymore) and so all infinite subsets are examples of bounded, closed and non-compact subsets.

To give a less trivial example: the closed unit ball in $\ell^2$ (the Hilbert space, in its standard norm/metric) is bounded closed and non-compact (as the $e_n$ do not have a convergent subsequence e.g.).

Another example of a different kind is the closed and bounded subset $[\frac12,1)$ of $(0,1)$ in its standard inherited metric. This is also non-compact...

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, thanks for your answer. $A$ is closed set...Can I say like this? $A$ is closed because any two distinct point has distance $1$, so if we choose an open ball $B(a, 2)$ for all $a \in A$, then $A$ is contained in $B(a,2)$, hence bounded. Am I coorect?

Comment: @user454229 boundedness can be put that way, yes. And if $x \notin A$, then $B_d(x,1)=\{x\}$ is disjoint from $A$ so $A$ is closed.